# c - printing the number of lines with unbalanced parentheses

Tags: c

I'm writing a parsing parentheses program that examines if a text file, written in c, has unbalanced parentheses. Now I'm trying to print the number of lines that cause the problem but got stuck. Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define bool int

/* structure of a stack node */
struct sNode
{
   char data;
   struct sNode *next;
};

/* Function to push an item to stack*/
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, int new_data);

/* Function to pop an item from stack*/
int pop(struct sNode** top_ref);

/* Returns 1 if character1 and character2 are matching left
   and right Parenthesis */
bool isMatchingPair(char character1, char character2)
{
   if (character1 == '(' && character2 == ')')
     return 1;
   else if (character1 == '{' && character2 == '}')
     return 1;
   else if (character1 == '[' && character2 == ']')
     return 1;
   else
     return 0;
}

/*Return 1 if expression has balanced Parenthesis */
bool areParenthesisBalanced(char exp[])
{
   int i = 0;

   /* Declare an empty character stack */
   struct sNode *stack = NULL;

   /* Traverse the given expression to check matching parenthesis */
   while (exp[i])
   {
      /*If the exp[i] is a starting parenthesis then push it*/
      if (exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '[')
        push(&stack, exp[i]);

      /* If exp[i] is an ending parenthesis then pop from stack and 
          check if the popped parenthesis is a matching pair*/
      else if (exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == ']')
      {

          /*If we see an ending parenthesis without a pair then return false*/
         if (stack == NULL)
         {
            printf("\nError: Closing parenthesis is not matched\n");
            return 0; 
         }

         /* Pop the top element from stack, if it is not a pair 
            parenthesis of character then there is a mismatch.
            This happens for expressions like {(}) */
         else if ( !isMatchingPair(pop(&stack), exp[i]) )
         {
            pop(&stack);
            return 0;
         }
      }
      i++;
   }

   /* If there is something left in expression then there is a starting
      parenthesis without a closing parenthesis */
   if (stack == NULL)
     return 1; /*balanced*/
   else
   {
    printf("\nError: Opening parenthesis not matched\n");
    return 0;  /*not balanced*/
   }
} 

/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/*driver program to test above functions*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* file = fopen("hw3.txt", "r"); /* should check the result */
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) 
    {
        /* note that fgets don't strip the terminating \n, checking its
           presence would allow to handle lines longer that sizeof(line) */
        areParenthesisBalanced(line);
    }
    /* may check feof here to make a difference between eof and io failure -- network
       timeout for instance */

    fclose(file);   

  /*char exp[100] = "{()}[]abc(";
  printf("%s", &exp);
  areParenthesisBalanced(exp);*/
  return 0;
}    

/* Function to push an item to stack*/
void push(struct sNode** top_ref, int new_data)
{
  /* allocate node */
  struct sNode* new_node =
            (struct sNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct sNode));

  if (new_node == NULL)
  {
     printf("Stack overflow n");
     getchar();
     exit(0);
  }           

  /* put in the data  */
  new_node->data  = new_data;

  /* link the old list off the new node */
  new_node->next = (*top_ref);  

  /* move the head to point to the new node */
  (*top_ref)    = new_node;
}

/* Function to pop an item from stack*/
int pop(struct sNode** top_ref)
{
  char res;
  struct sNode *top;

  /*If stack is empty then error */
  if (*top_ref == NULL)
  {
     printf("Stack overflow n");
     getchar();
     exit(0);
  }
  else
  {
     top = *top_ref;
     res = top->data;
     *top_ref = top->next;
     free(top);
     return res;
  }
}
```

I'm thinking about adding index for each line imported and concatenating all strings into a single expression. For instance, turning

`1 first line
2 second line
3 third line`

into 
`1 first line 2 second line 3 third line` because `areParenthesisBalanced` cannot matching parenthesis across different lines.

I've tried several methods but non of them worked.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---EDIT---

To be more specific, my main question is how to examine the whole file and print the error lines with index number.

Comment: In the loop reading the lines, you have to check what `areParenthesisBalanced` returns. If it returns zero then increase a counter.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how can I concatenate those different lines and the counter into a single expression in practical? I've thought of `strcat()` but don't know how to use it since it only concatenates two strings.

Comment: What is you *main* question? How to check the balance of the *whole* file? Or how to count the number of lines with mismatched balance? Those are really two different questions, and one is very easy to answer (read the whole file into a single memory block).

Comment: I've edited my question to be more explicit. Thank you.

Comment: regarding the statement: `#define bool int` that is a very poor idea.  Much better to use: `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: The posted code is missing a check for '\n' so does not know what line it is on.  There should be a variable that contains the current line number (starts with 1 and increments each time a '\n' is input.  That current line number is what the code should be displaying when trying to tell the user where the problem is found.

Comment: could match across lines if the instance of `struct sNode` were either located in `main()` and passed as a '**' to the called function =or= were a global variable.  You could also keep the current line count in that struct so it is always available.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) consistently indent the code.  suggest each indent level be 4 spaces, not some random 1 or 2 spaces.  3) suggest separating functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` so the appropriate info is displayed on `stderr`, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Stack overflow n");` and similar statements.  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` Suggest using `perror();` when error from a system function and using `fprintf( stderr, "..." );` when the code developed the error.

Comment: in function: `areParenthesisBalanced()` this statement: `while (exp[i])` would be much better written as: `for( int i=0; exp[i]; i++ )`  and remove the declaration of 'i' and the incrementing of 'i' from the loop.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11` )